# OpenCV Brightness & Contrast like in Gimp

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, gimp

I want adjust the contrast in Python's OpenCV like in Gimp. I want do this:
[image]

In Gimp it is simple. I just use `Colors->Brightness & Contrast`, and set contrast to `127`. 
But I don't know how to do this in Python and I cannot find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://pippin.gimp.org/image_processing/chap_point.html). The formula is:

```
new_value = (old_value - 0.5) × contrast + 0.5 + brightness
```

In python you can easily apply these as matrix operations. Please note that pixel values here are in [0,1], so 0.5 is equivalent to 127 when the range is in [0,255].

In the same link is reported also the code, with pixel-wise operations (I copy just for completeness):

```
function transform(value, brightness, contrast)
  return (value-0.5)*contrast+0.5+brightness
end

function transform_rgb(r,g,b, brightness, contrast)
  return transform(r, brightness, contrast), transform(g, brightness, contrast), transform(b, brightness, contrast)
end

function bcontrast_get_rgb(x,y,brightness, contrast)
   r,g,b=get_rgb(x,y)
   return transform_rgb(r,g,b, brightness, contrast)
end

function bcontrast(brightness, contrast)
    for y=0, height-1 do
      for x=0, width-1 do
        set_rgb(x,y, bcontrast_get_rgb(x,y,brightness,contrast))
      end
    end
    flush ()
end

bcontrast(0.25, 2.0)
```

Comment: What is the range of the birghtness and contrast values? In Gimp those values ranges from -127 to 127. But with bcontrast(0.25,2.0) it seems not to be in this field. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't konw. You should check the gimp source code for that. It probably make sense to have the contrast in (0,10), and brightness in (-1, 1). You should also take care of clamping to 0 negative pixel values, and to 1 bigger values. @ChristianGold

Answer (score 2):

The formula for contrast and brightness used by GIMP is defined in this file : https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/GIMP_2_10_10/app/operations/gimpoperationbrightnesscontrast.c

```
  if (brightness < 0.0)
    value = value * (1.0 + brightness);
  else
    value = value + ((1.0 - value) * brightness);

  value = (value - 0.5) * slant + 0.5;
```

Where

```
  brightness = config->brightness / 2.0;
  slant = tan ((config->contrast + 1) * G_PI_4);
```

Assuming the image was normalized to the [0, 1] range beforehand.

Comment: For some reason I thought GIMP would be doing this kind of simple stuff on the GPU by now... performs magnitudes faster.